# Find integrating factor for $2(1+\sin^2(x))\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin(2x)y=x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

There's differential equation $2(1+\sin^2(x))\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin(2x)y=x$. Then what is integrating factor. First I convert it to standard form $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$. And integrating factor is $e^{\int P(x)dx}$. But first to find $P(x)$ I should rearrange it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The3 Integrating factor is $I=\exp(J)$, use $t=\tan^2 x$
$$J=\int \frac{\sin 2x dx}{2(1+2\sin^2 x)} =\int \frac{\tan x \sec^2x}{(1+2\tan^2 x)(1+\tan^2 x)} =\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{(1+t)(1+2t)}.$$
$$J=\frac{1}{2}\int \left(\frac{2}{1+2t}- \frac{1}{1+t}\right)dt=  \frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1+2t}{1+t}$$
So $$I =\sqrt{\frac{1+2\tan^2 x}{1+\tan^2x}}= \sqrt{1+\sin ^2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should divided the equation by the coefficient of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, The integrating factor is root over $1+\sin^2 x$.

Answer (score 0):

Either divide by $2(1+\sin^2 x)$ to find $P(x)=\sin(2x)/[2(1+\sin^2 x)]$ and hence $e^{\int^x P}$ and the actual integrating factor $e^{\int^x P}/[2(1+\sin^2 x)]$, or just note $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[2(1+\sin^2 x)]=2\sin 2x$ almost gets you there so you just need to multiply by an appropriate power of $(1+\sin^2 x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you rearrange your equation nicely and bring it to the form $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$ you'll notice that $$P(x) = \frac{\sin 2x}{2(1+\sin^2 x)} , Q(x) = \frac{x}{2(1+\sin^2 x)}$$
where $\displaystyle y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$. You want to find $\displaystyle e^{\int P(x)dx}$, so I'll tell how to find $\int P(x)dx$.
$$\int \frac{\sin 2x}{2(1+\sin^2 x)} dx = \int \frac{du}{2u} = \frac{\ln u}{2} + C = \frac{\ln (1+\sin^2x)}{2} + C$$
where $u = 1+\sin^2 x \implies du  = \sin2x dx$. Let $C = 0$ (think why we can do this), to get $\displaystyle e^{\int P(x)dx} = \sqrt{1 + \sin^2x }$, which is your required integrating factor!

Answer (score 0):

If you divide by the coefficient of $y'$, your equation is written in the standard form with
$$
P(x)=\frac{\sin 2x}{2(1+\sin^2x)}=\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1+\sin^2x}
$$
The integrating factor is
$$
\mu(x)=\exp (\int P(x)\,dx)=\exp [\ln(1+\sin^2x)/2]=\sqrt{1+\sin^2 x}
$$